# Search Youtube video by Keyword using Java

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I want to use YouTube search option using Youtube data API in my own YouTube application. Now i can play only one video using YouTube Video id using youtube data api version 3.

is it possible to make a such kind of **ANDROID APPLICATION**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

request `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=SEARCH_YOUR_TEXT&type=video&maxResults=50&key=YOUR_APP_KEY"`
return JsonArray where u parse video id